# how to keep Navigation drawer icon stationary on click?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to keep the nav drawer icon stationary, instead of it moving left and right when I click on it. Is this possible, and how can this be done?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean)   i think that is the method to use to stop the animation.